# error while capturing video/image in vidcap python27

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

When i type this code :

```
import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
import pygame.image
pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
pygame.camera.quit()
```

I get an error : but i can see my webcam light to lit up ....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\Bill2.py", line 7, in <module>
    pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your platform is win32, so the `Camera` class that pygame imports is located in `Python27\Lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py`. It looks like that the method `Camera.get_image()` is not returning a surface, that might be because this method internally uses the `pygame.image` module, which is not initialized yet.

I suggest you to initialize the modules first, and then get the image to finally save it. I also suggest you to delete the camera object and quit the modules.

```
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
del cam
pygame.camera.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

PS: On my machine, I had to comment the statement `self.dev.setresolution(width, height)` in `Camera.__init__`, since it does work for my webcam.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\python\transpose.py", line 9, in <module>
    pygame.image.save(img, "photo.bmp")
TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not None   .. it gives this error